# Session works in one page but not another

Tags: php, image, session, href, src

I am working in a php charting package. I start with a form.html that sends to an answer.php page. The answer.php creates the SESSION. Then a required test.php page picks up the session but the required graph.php page does not. I cannot transfer my data from the form to the graph. The required phplot.php is the graph engine and is not needed in the SESSION thread.

I have spent five days researching and testing with no luck. I have switched the coding around many times. I'm hoping that someone with great php experience will recognize something easily.

The coding for the three pages is below.

answer.php page:

```
<?php
session_unset();
session_start();
require_once 'phplot/test.php';
?>
<?php
$_POST['bs_now2'];$bs_now2 = $_POST['bs_now2'];$_SESSION['bs_now2'] = $bs_now2;
echo "<div id='graph'>";
echo "<p class='martop10 f18 b'>Graph:</p>";
echo "<img src='phplot/graph.php'>";
echo "</div>";
?>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

graph.php page:

```
<?php
$Sbs_now2 == 0;
session_start();# Is this redundant? I've tried it in and out.
?>
<?php
require_once 'phplot.php';#Graph engine
$delta = 0.1;$sigma = 15;$sqrt2pi = sqrt(2*M_PI);$u = 75;
$data = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 150; $x++)
  $data[] = array('', $x, $Sbs_now2 + $x);
unset($Sbs_now2);
?>
```

test.php page:

```
<?php
#I don't need the session_start() for this page
$_POST['bs_now2'];$bs_now2 = $_POST['bs_now2'];$_SESSION['bs_now2'] = $bs_now2;$Sbs_now2 = $_SESSION['bs_now2'];
echo '<b>Session BS Now: '.$Sbs_now2.'</b><br>';
?>
```

Thank you,

Gary

Comment: Please add more details to your question, look here for how to provide a sample code : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you. I just reformatted the post as I am new and learning the forum.

Answer (score 0):

First thing In every page you will use "$_SESSION" you need to start session through "session_start()" if session start is not present in the code you can not get data from $ _SESSION variable, I recommend using $_POST variable Your php session is not full and does not cause problems

Use this: (Pass throught $_POST)

```
<?php
// passing data to the post
$_POST['data'] = "Test using Post";
// Receiving the data from the post
$data = $_POST['data'];
// to test and see if it works
echo $_POST['data']; // or echo $data
```

Hope i have helped

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried all the combinations of session_start() and it works on the one page but I'm not sure about the other page. The data must be an iteration, or list, of numerals from x=0 through x=150. I am intrigued with the (Pass through $_POST) option. I searched for it and it seems to be a second choice after trying session.

Comment: @landt5 Youre Welcome

Comment: Upon further research, I have found an angle that maybe sessions and other functions can't be passed through when 'src' is used as compared to 'href' or 'require' or 'include'. Does anyone know if this is true?

Comment: You can store the session data as a string in a variable and pass the data through a href or a src or URL

Comment: use the echo to pass the variable data at the href

Comment: Thank you Luiz Fernando Sousa Camargo. I will research your posts tomorrow and try the fixes. More research has shown me that sessions won't transfer in an html manner.

Comment: I tried to post an answer but it will not go through. Luiz Fernando Sousa Camargo greatly helped me solve the problem. I joined "?bs_now2=$Sbs_now2" to the end of the src address as in <img src='phplot/hr9.php?bs_now2=$Sbs_now2>. Gary

Answer (score 0):

Hi Luiz Fernando Sousa Camargo and All,

With help from Luiz Fernando Sousa Camargo I have got it!

answer.php page has one change:

```
<?php
session_unset();
session_start();
require_once 'phplot/test1.php';
?>
<?php
$_POST['bs_now2'];$bs_now2 = $_POST['bs_now2'];$_SESSION['bs_now2'] = $bs_now2;$Sbs_now2 = $_SESSION['bs_now2'];
echo "<div id='graph'>";
echo "<p class='martop10 f18 b'>Graph:</p>";
echo "<img src='phplot/bs4c.php?bs_now2=$Sbs_now2'>";#CHANGE:
#I set bs_now2= to the session variable(as it would come from the form input). No other changes.
echo "</div>";
?>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

graph.php page has a one important change:

```
<?php
$Sbs_now2 == 0;
session_start();
$_GET['bs_now2'];$bs_now2 = $_GET['bs_now2'];$_SESSION['bs_now2'] = $bs_now2;$Sbs_now2 = $_SESSION['bs_now2'];#CHANGE
#Use GET to acquire the session variable
#Remove End php and Start php Marks(not important)
require_once 'phplot.php';
$data = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 150; $x++)
  $data[] = array('', $x, $Sbs_now2 + $x);
unset($Sbs_now2);
?>
```

Thank you Luiz Fernando Sousa Camargo and All,

Gary

Comment: How does one rate the member(s) that contributed to the Answer? I would like to cite Luiz Fernando Sousa Camargo for his contribution.