# Session works only on one page in php

Tags: php, session

I set session variable for login of user but it doesn't work on another pages than login.php.

**login.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {       

        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'cp72722_lucky', '3AIp!9f4', 'cp72722_lucky');
        $user_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['username']));
        $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['password']));
        if(!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password)) {

            $query = "SELECT user_id , username FROM users WHERE username = '$user_username' AND pwd = SHA('$user_password')";
            $data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {

                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);                               
                $user_value = $row['username'];             
                $user_id_value = $row['user_id'];               
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user_value;
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id_value;              
                echo "Hello," . $_SESSION['username'];          
                $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];                
                header('Location: ' . $home_url);               
                print_r($home_url);
                exit();
            }
            else {
                echo 'Извините, вы должны ввести правильные имя пользователя и пароль';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'Извините, вы должны заполнить поля правильно';
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Главная</a></li>

</ul>
</header>
<h2>Вход</h2>
<div class="container">
<form action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>" method="POST">
        <label for="username">Логин:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <label for="password">Пароль:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Вход</button>
    <a href="auth/signup.php">Регистрация</a>
    </form>
    </div>
<footer>
    <p>Все права защищены</p>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

My header.php shows almost on all pages and I want to welcome the users after login. If the session is not set, then should display the form to login. Problem is, if the user is logged in and the profile links, it always displays second choice because session is not set. How do I resolve this issue?

**header.php:**

```
<?php

session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);
?>
...
<header id="header">
    <?php
echo 'Glad to see you,'. htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']);
?>
...
<div>
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <label for="username">Login:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Enter</button>
    <a href="auth/signup.php">Registration</a>
    </form>
<?php
}
else {
    ?>
    <p><a href="myprofile.php">Profile</a></p>
    <p><a href="exit.php">Exit(<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>)</a></p>
<?php   
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session works in one page but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146310/session-works-in-one-page-but-not-another).

Comment: Change the order of your display or just do if (! isset($_SESSION['username']))

Comment: `if($_SESSION['username'])` means that `$_SESSION['username']` is true. Instead you should use isset function to check if session is set

Comment: You start the session but i can't see where you set session data?

Comment: @stefo91 it is in the middle of login.php

$_SESSION['username'] = $user_value;
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id_value;

Comment: @quickSwap I saw this post but it couldn't help me

Comment: If you are using secure cookies over http then this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294582/php-session-variables-disappear-on-new-page-and-return-empty/56361653#56361653 may be the answer

Comment: @Mark_1 i use session though thanks i'll check it also

Comment: By default PHP uses a cookie to store the session id, if you have secure cookies set in your php.ini and are not browsing your site over HTTPS PHP will not read the session cookie and will start a new session for every page.

Answer (score 1):

`if($_SESSION['username'])` means that `$_SESSION['username']` is true. Instead, you should use an [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function to check if the session is set. Your code should look like this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {//If $_SESSION['username'] is not set then show the login form
?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <label for="username">Login:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Enter</button>
    <a href="auth/signup.php">Registration</a>
    </form>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Actually i had isset and empty there and it didn't work anyway.

Comment: Remove extra space before `session_start();`

Comment: I have only one space after <?php before session_start();

Answer (score -1):

Remove extra space before `session_start()` function

**convert :**

```
    <?php

    session_start();
```

to this

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Thank you.

Comment: I did it - doesn't matter

Comment: i think when you are checking the database with username and password there is no matach found so its going to else condition try to echo the query and check for the result in the database, may be it will works

Comment: No, it is not. When i submit login and password on login.php without redirect to main page it echoes this string with matched username from db
echo "Hello," . $_SESSION['username'];

Comment: hey bro if you are using full https ://example.com/index.php full url to redirect from one page to another your sessions will be lost try to use lik header("Location:index.php")

Comment: change $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];   to $html_url = "index.php" in login .php page it will works i think. 
thank you.

Comment: I don't get why it will be lost but session doesn't work anyway

Comment: if your using full domain and page name to redirect from one page to another php thinks that your redirecting from your server to some other server so php remove all the session variables for that you need to use only the page name instead of full domain name